# Use Twitter Bootstrap with FontAwesome in ExpressJS

Tags: node.js, express

I want to combine [`Twitter Bootstrap`](http://getbootstrap.com/) and [`FontAwesome`](http://fontawesome.io/) with [`ExoressJS`](http://expressjs.com/).

I have tried to do it with

```
npm install twitter-bootstrap
```

howewer it points to the `2.1.1` version ([ref](https://npmjs.org/package/twitter-bootstrap)) which is quite old. The same thing about [`font-awesome`](https://npmjs.org/package/font-awesome) npm package. How to combine those packages with `ExpressJS` and stay up to date with the new releases ?

Comment: You should use Bower instead for your front end libraries. http://bower.io/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twitter Bootstrap and FontAwesome are client side libraries, I recommend you to use a client side package manager instead of npm (server side pack manager).

I think the best client side pack manager is [Bower](http://bower.io/)

Only run that commands:

```
npm install bower -g
bower install bootstrap --save
bower install font-awesome --save
```

I hope I have helped!

Answer (score 3):

create a file named bower.json

**/bower.json**

```
{
    "name": "project-name",
    "dependencies": {
        "bootstrap": "3.x",
        "jquery": "1.x",
        "font-awesome": "*"
    }
}
```

then

> bower install

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that font awesome is also a client side lib.

I recommend simply having a **public/vendor** folder and saving the newest versions manually in there. You can then reference them from the views like normal css/js.